# Stop ckeditor from adding non amp codes

Tags: ckeditor, amp-html

Is there a way to make ckeditor compatible with AMP?
ckeditor keeps adding inline styles to images tags which spoils AMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use any inline styles for content created in CKEditor, please try using the following (**Advanced Content Filter (ACF) can't be disabled for this to work**):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        allowedContent : {
            $1: {
                // This will set the default set of elements.
                elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
                attributes: true,
                styles: false,
                classes: true
            }
        }
});
```

If you only want to disallow styles for images, please use:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {             
                 disallowedContent : 'img{width,height}'
});
```

To learn more about ACF, please see:

- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-addTransformations
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent
- http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent